# Styling Recurly.js input fields

Tags: recurly

Does anyone know how to directly style an input field generated by recurly.js? It injects input fields into the page through iframes. Their documentation gives classes that are added the the divs or spans (whatever you use) surrounding the iframe but they have styles alredy loaded in the  of the iframe and I can't figure out how to override them.

Thanks!

[recurly docs](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/getting-started-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styling of payment fields injected within the iframe can be done through the CSS section of recurly.config() in the recurly sign-up page https://dev.recurly.com/docs/getting-started-1#section-styling-card-fields.  This enables the styles to be applied on the hosted payment fields when the recurly sign-up page is loaded.

Comment: Ok. So, does this mean I can add styles directly into the style option in recurly.config() like border, borderColor, padding, width, etc... or do I need to initiate these styles when I sign up for the product?

Comment: The hosted payment fields styling of the iframe are configured in the styling section of Recurly.config(). Non-iframe styling would be done through conventional CSS styling for the form.

Comment: @RachelQuick broken link

Comment: Im having trouble with this aswell today. I cant seem to understand how to style the individual card elements. Also why is the Card image not available on CardNumberElement but its available on CardElement? When you use individual card elements you lose the ability to show the mastercard, visa emblem...

Answer (score 0):

updated link: https://dev.recurly.com/docs/recurly-js-getting-started

you can add styles to recurly.config

```
recurly.config({
  publicKey: ...,
  style: {
    all: {
      fontSize: '16px',
      fontColor: 'green',
      placeholder: {
        color: 'gray !important',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  }
});
```